# Please convert into passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

What will be the passive voice of the following sentence?

> "They have made a film based on this novel."

Answer (score 0):

The passive voice for the sentence "They have made a film based on this novel." can be phrased as:

> A film **has been made** based on this novel.

You could also add who using "by":

> A film has been made **by them** based on this novel.

The passive voice is formed by using "be + past participle" in this case "be made". And then you change be to the correct tense, which is in your case present perfect, so "be" becomes (a film) "has been", this gives you "a film has been made."